# Check whether all the sub tests are passed TEST::MORE

Tags: perl

I want to check whether all the sub tests are pass or fail .if all the sub test are pass then I will want perform some action based on the result

```
use Test::More;
use warnings;
use strict;

my $test  = 5;
my $test1 = 5;
subtest 'TESTCASE_001' => sub {
    is( $test1, 6, "xyz111 mmdmmd11 value are same" );
    is( $test,  5, "uuuuu12 mmdmmd value are same" );
};

my $string = &TESTCASE_001 ? 'pass' : 'fail';

if ( $string =~ /pass/ ) {
    'delete xyz from table .............some SQL queries....';
}
else {
    'do nothing ';
}
done_testing();
```

How to check that subtest 'TESTCASE_001' is Pass or fail ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`subtest` returns true or false depending on whether all subtests passed.

```
my $subtest_ok = subtest 'TESTCASE_001' => sub {      
   is($test1,6, "xyz111 mmdmmd11 value are same");
   is($test,5, "uuuuu12 mmdmmd value are same");
};

if ($subtest_ok) {
   ...;
}
else {
   ...;
}
```

Also useful is `Test::Builder->new->is_passing` which returns false if *any test has failed so far*.